# Run Java Maven program from Linux terminal: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, linux, maven, exception, terminal

I have Java maven project that read Json file and get some data.
But I can not run my program by Linux Terminal.

package name: my

classname: StartProgram

OS Ubuntu 20.04.2.064

Maven 3.6.3

Java 14.0.2

I did next steps:

```
mvn clean install
cd target
java -cp jsonReader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar my.StartProgram
```

the output:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class my.StartProgram
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.StartProgram
```

Part of my pom.xml:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>my.StartProgram</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

How I can fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the StartProgram code please...

Comment: https://github.com/mariamura/jsonReader/blob/master/src/main/java/StartProgram.java  (but without updated POM.xml and without packages 'my'). Is it OK for you?)

Comment: Where are you getting `my` from? I see you have no package. Try running `java -cp jsonReader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar StartProgram`

Comment: I already try all options (with created 'my' packages and without)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simply way in project directory:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="StartProgram"
```

### Another way:

Your project depends on another external library, so when you use `java -cp ...` you mast provide all of them.

you can build dependency list by (need run once once when your pom chanegs):

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt
```

and then you can run your program by:

```
java -cp `cat cp.txt`:target/jsonReader-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar StartProgram
```

Comment: Yes! It works!!) thank you) One more question: how can i execute that it display only results of StartProgram ? Thank you one more time!

Comment: try run with `mvn -q`